# Find faces from triangles mesh

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

I have got structure like that.

```
struct triangle {
    point a, b, c; // three dimensional point (x, y, z)
}
vector<triangle> triangles
```

I need to write an algorithm to get unique faces from this triangles mesh.

I was trying to find out information about this, but all what fount is this method: http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/3d/ofMesh.html#show_getUniqueFaces

Unfortunetaly, I cannot add-in any frameworks to my program.
I am kinda low in geometry so I will be very glad if someone give me some tips.

Comment: So, what have you tried? What is your question?

Comment: @Escualo sorry. I have updated the message.

Answer (score 1):

Make a graph in which the nodes are the triangles.  Two triangles have an edge between them if they share two vertices and their normal vectors are less than A degrees apart (dot(u, v) > cos(A)).  Find connected components in the graph.  Each connected component corresponds to a set of triangles that form a face of the mesh.

The closer A is to 0, the smoother the definition of a "face" of the mesh.